# How can I improve performance my geography update query in SQL Server 2008 using STDistance?

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008, t-sql, spatial

I am having serious performance issues with a spatial update query in SQL Server 2008 (not R2) using STDistance(). The goal is simple enough: I have a table with 120,000 records, **Houses** with the column **NearestLibrary**. I have a second table with 12 records, **Libraries** with the column **Name**. Both tables have a geography column **LatLngGeography**. I want to update **Houses.NearestLibrary** with the name of the closest library from **Libraries**.

This query takes around 50 seconds to run:

```
UPDATE Houses
    SET NearestLibrary = (
    SELECT TOP 1 Name
    FROM Libraries
    ORDER BY Houses.LatLngGeography.STDistance(Libraries.LatLngGeography)
)
```

That would almost be acceptable, except that when I run it for Parks instead of Libraries where I have about 100 parks, it takes almost 10 times as long. Both tables have properly constructed spatial indexes named IX_Houses_LatLngGeography and IX_Libraries_LatLngGeography respectively but thus far I have been unable to work out how make my query use them.

Is there a way to improve the performance of my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an "Index Hint".

```
UPDATE Houses     
SET NearestLibrary = (     
    SELECT TOP 1 Name     
    FROM Libraries WITH(INDEX( SPATIAL_INDEX_NAME_HERE ))
    ORDER BY Houses.LatLngGeography.STDistance(Libraries.LatLngGeography) 
)
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion here and the following error was thrown:

Query processor could not produce a query plan because of the hints defined in this query. Resubmit the query without specifying any hints and without using SET FORCEPLAN.

Comment: Have you got a spatial index on the table?

Comment: Here is my spatial index. Is there anything wrong with it?

    CREATE SPATIAL INDEX [NDX_Libraries_LatLngGeography] ON [dbo].[Libraries] 
    (
     [LatLngGeography]
    )USING  GEOGRAPHY_GRID 
    WITH (
    GRIDS =(LEVEL_1 = MEDIUM,LEVEL_2 = MEDIUM,LEVEL_3 = MEDIUM,LEVEL_4 = MEDIUM), 
    CELLS_PER_OBJECT = 16, PAD_INDEX  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    GO`

Comment: Urgh. Sorry - I can't work out how to insert line breaks in my comments. I'm new to stackoverflow

Comment: I inserted NDX_Libraries_LatLngGeography in place of SPATIAL_INDEX_NAME_HERE but otherwise the code is identical to what you suggested.

Comment: does the select statement work on its own?  without the update that is?

Comment: Err... well - if I take out The "UPDATE Houses" part, the "ORDER BY Houses.LatLngGeography" part of the SELECT statement will be broken. Shall I try it with a DECLAREd geometry variable instead of Houses.LatLngGeography in the ORDER BY clause?

Comment: Nope. It doesn't work no matter what. Here's what I tried:

`DECLARE @centre geography = 'POINT(-0.0182395 51.59816)';
SELECT TOP 1 Name
FROM Libraries WITH(INDEX(NDX_Libraries_LatLngGeography))
ORDER BY @centre.STDistance(Libraries.LatLngGeography)`

Comment: The above fails with the same error has before about being unable to create plan

Comment: Ahh, yes I see.  Theres no join clause in the select statement.  No idea if it would work , but could you put the index hint at the end of the query?  i.e. outside the brackets?

Comment: Alas: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929109%28v=sql.110%29.aspx, it seems a query MUST have a WHERE clause that uses STDistance. In SQL Server Denali, that WHERE clause can be where the STDistance result is NOT NULL, but in 2008 it has to be greater than or less than something. I tried adding a where clause where the distance is less than 100km, and it let me run with the spatial index, but actually took about four times as long to run the query!

Comment: Im not sure your going to be able to make it work unless the select has a join in it.  Any chance you can?

Comment: I'm looking towards radically altering the shape of the query, somehow JOINing on STDistance rather than updating each row with a subquery, but it's proving extremely difficult. Thanks for your efforts and if you have any further ideas please do let me know...

Comment: I'm open to any kind of radical change in the way that the query is designed. What I'm looking at right now is creating a temporary table with the MIN() distance of all the libraries from each house, and doing some kind of JOIN against that temporary table. Not there yet though...

Comment: Well, you can do an INNER JOIN using .STDistance() but limiting the max distiance.  for example:  a.geog.STDistance(b.Geog) < 500 -  (less than 500m)... not sure if that will help.

Comment: There's another massive disadvantage in the original design of my query - it's only capable of updating one field in the houses table. A second field would double the query time since each field is updated with an independent subquery

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got the execution time down somewhat using a temporary table. Here is my end result query:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempDistances') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TempDistances
CREATE TABLE #TempDistances (
    HouseID varchar(20),
    Distance float
)

INSERT INTO #TempDistances
SELECT h.HouseID, MIN(h.LatLngGeography.STDistance(l.LatLngGeography)) AS Distance
FROM (SELECT * FROM Houses) AS h
LEFT JOIN Libraries AS l
ON h.LatLngGeography.STDistance(l.LatLngGeography) IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY h.HouseID

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX TempDistances_HouseID ON #TempDistances (HouseID)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX TempDistances_Distance ON #TempDistances (Distance)

UPDATE h
SET NearestLibraryID = l.ID,
NearestLibraryName = l.Name,
NearestLibraryURL = l.URL,
NearestLibraryDistance = t.Distance
FROM (Houses AS h
   INNER JOIN #TempDistances AS t ON h.HouseID = t.LPINumber)
       INNER JOIN Libraries AS l ON h.LatLngGeography.STDistance(l.LatLngGeography) = t.Distance

DROP TABLE #TempDistances
```

It's still not really as fast as I would like, but it does the nearest parks in 8 minutes instead of 40, so I'm a lot happier than I was. Thanks to @CatchingMonkey for trying to help.